# Copy files from path to path same structure for each user

Tags: linux, centos, bash, copy

How to copy files from source

```
/backup/cpbackup/daily/a1/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/b2/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/c3/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/d4/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/e5/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/f6/public_html/index.html
```

to destination

```
/home/a1/public_html/index.html
/home/b2/public_html/index.html
/home/c3/public_html/index.html
/home/c4/public_html/index.html
/home/e5/public_html/index.html
/home/f6/public_html/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it (assuming you're trying to copy all the files over):

```
rsync -a /backup/cpbackup/daily/user* /home/
```

If you want just index.html and nothing else:

```
rsync -av --include=*/ --include=*public_html/index.html --exclude=* /backup/cpbackup/daily/user* /home/
```

Comment: the user not like user 1 and user 2 , it's example , i mention usernames like jogn and smith not all have the same user name folder

Comment: Then substitute * for user* `rsync -a /backup/cpbackup/daily/* /home/`

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to do it:

```
for user in user1 user2 user3 user4 user5 user6; do
  cp /backup/cpbackup/daily/$user/public_html/index.html /home/$user/public_html/
done
```